# When will Twilio Flex support outbound calling?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

Im wondering when the engineering team at Twilio expects to release the outbound dialing functionality, which was indicated is being actively worked on here

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010789173-How-do-I-Make-Outbound-Calls-with-Twilio-Flex-

I'd imagine a lot of people leveraging twilio flex would like this as its a common case.

I realize that we can add this type of functionality on our own by programming against the apis, and even use the plugin such as
https://github.com/lehel-twilio/plugin-dialpad

My only concern with using the above plugin is that it

- May be deprecated if twilio engineers add this natively to flex UI
- Since only 1 plugin can be used at a time, if customizations were made to a plugin already (call it plugin B), I would have to merge the plugin code contained in the plugin-dialpad github repo above (call this plugin A) into the code base of Plugin B.

It would be great if twilio supported adding mutiple plugins?

Any feedback twilio team/evangelists on this? Id imagine its a common use case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. This site is not for questions related to future plans or timelines for features. Contact the project or vendor directly for questions related to theie future plans.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The team has kindly responded and said that they are targeting the end of year for releasing this natively into twilio flex

Answer (score 0):

it's already available but experimental
https://www.twilio.com/changelog/outbound-calling-experimental-feature

here is a guide on setup
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/dialpad-end-user-guide

there is a confusing part with workflow thing so I'm going to explain in more details:

1) go to https://www.twilio.com/console/taskrouter/workspaces

2) select your workspace

3) go to Workflows

4) click on Assign to Anyone or whatever workflow you want to use for outbound calls

5) Click Add filter

6) If you have other filters it's better to place this one on top because if other filter matches this task it won't work

7) set MATCHING TASKS to `flexOutboundDialerTargetWorker != null`

8) set EXPRESSION to `task.flexOutboundDialerTargetWorker == worker.contact_uri`

9) click save

that's it. hope it saves someone time

Answer (score 0):

Flex supports outbound dialing in form of the following two features

- Native [Dialpad](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/dialpad/use) available in Flex UI
- Programmability construct viz. startOutboundCall to build use cases like [click-to-dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/dialpad/implementing-click-to-dial).

starting today.

Check out the [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/flex-programmable-dialpad-outbound-calling).

Disclaimer : I work at Twilio.